# Windows program for most opened folders?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, filesystems

I am planning to move to a new computer and want to locally back up my most-used folders, and leave the rest on the cloud. It would be great if a program has already been written for this, like the one I found for the most used programs ([UserAssist](https://blog.didierstevens.com/programs/userassist/)), but I am not averse to writing my own in Java for future use. Does Windows already keep track of this (like it does for most used programs), and it is just a matter of accessing it, or would I have to do this on my own? (Maybe the latter is more suited for SO, but it doesn't hurt to try the OS-knowledgeable community here.)

Comment: For your most used folders, I would try writing something on your own, possibly in Powershell.

Comment: @Anaksunaman .. how would he go about accessing this information via powershell?  Last I checked, this was a very difficult problem to solve without a minifilter written in c or c++.  Times change though.. please enlighten me.  BTW, Process Monitor uses a minifilter/driver.

Comment: One other thing, if you are going to try to keep track of every folder hit, powershell, java, or any other high level language is not going to be fast enough.

Comment: @paddywan all of my files are in the user directory and are already backed up to OneDrive. Just for convenience, I would like to have my most used folders available locally so that I don't have to download the potentially 50+ GBs from OneDrive, and I will leave the rest of my files for on-demand downloading when I need them. Notice how I phrased the question, "locally backup", and "leave the rest on the cloud".

Comment: > "all of my files are in the user directory and are already backed up"
and
>  "locally backup"

These are essentially the same thing, the only difference is the backup media which you will use a local disk instead of a network connection. There is absolutely no point in backing up anything from program files as you will be missing all associated registry configurations on your new install. It seems as though you know very well what you want to backup already, so I question the utility of this "most-read directory analytics".

Comment: Assuming OP still wants to proceed to generate directory usage statistics, then I suggest reading over: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b which is a simple script for watching directories. The script in question is written to monitor creations and changes, however it can also be adapted for read access via monitoring LastAccess: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.notifyfilters?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @paddywan I am not sure why you are bringing in program files. I had no intention of backing them up. I was explaining that the concern was for the files or folders which I use very often but don't remember at the time of backing up or don't realize in general that I use so often (both so I don't have to think through at the time of backup about the ones I use most often and worry about forgetting about some of them and not locally back them up, and having to wait a potentially long time to download them from the cloud.)

Comment: The point of the local backup is that it will be accessible more immediately and transferring locally has a higher transfer speed than my a network connection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115164/discussion-between-paddywan-and-sam).